# How to update tracker, a package which hasn't been updated in the PPA yet for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, tracker

I need the tracker package 2.3.0 version for the development of the Gnome Music App. The current version of the tracker package in PPA is 2.0.3 for Ubuntu 18.04. I want to install the tracker version >= 2.3.0 in Ubuntu 18.04. What is the generic way to override the existing older package with the latest one with all dependencies fulfilled?

I've tried downloading the Debian package of the tracker 2.3.0 and installing it by removing the older tracker package. But the newer tracker package 2.3.0's package doesn't have all the libraries which it requires.

Comment: If you are developing for 18.04, you should use standard 18.04 versions to avoid precisely the dependency problems that you are encountering. Haywiring a wrong-version dependency will make your app impossible for users to install. Is there some 2.3 feature that your app really needs?

Comment: I'm working on developing the latest gnome-music app. I'm not sure Gnome has mentioned any requirements about the native Gnome version. So I should be able to develop Gnome 3.36 app on Gnome 3.34?

Comment: Yes, but you will need an appropriate [Development Environment](https://developer.gnome.org/guides) to prevent version conflicts from breaking your system.